# Can I use MvcJsonOptions configured during Startup for serialization in custom middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am building an ASP.NET Core Api with a middleware for global exception handling. In `Startup` class, I configured some JSON options which are to be used for all controllers.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
            {
                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
            };
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        });
}
```

Then, I created a custom middleware for exceptions handling. The middleware is supposed to log the error and return error response as JSON. The problem is that global Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert` doesn't use the options which are specified during Mvc initialization (quite obvious).

Error handler middleware code:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex, logger);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex, ILogger logger)
    {
        var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse { Message = ex.Message };
        logger.LogError(ex, errorResponse.Message);

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

**The question is**: Is there any way to use the same JSON serializer, which is used in controllers, in my custom middleware? I would like to avoid setting up the same configuration in two separate places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` has an [overload that also takes an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_5.htm), which could be combined with the options pattern and dependency injection. All-in-all, that would look something like this:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializerSettings;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> mvcJsonOptions)
    {
        _next = next;
        _jsonSerializerSettings = mvcJsonOptions.Value.SerializerSettings;
    }

    ...

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex, ILogger logger)
    {
        ...
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse, _jsonSerializerSettings);
        ...
    }
}
```

In this example, we're injecting the `MvcJsonOptions` instance that's been configured and then passing its `SerializerSettings` value through to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

Comment: This is the line that helped me: _jsonSerializerSettings = mvcJsonOptions.Value.SerializerSettings; because even though I have set the "ignore" option on loops, code in another class wasn't using the option, so I had to inject the options with IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>, but then I didn't know what to do with it (I wasn't even sure if the right Json converter was being used!)